# How to play and change audio by swiping image in Android

Tags: android, audio, swipe

i have created a simple android project which will display various images stored in an array and change audio by swiping image. 
here is my code

```
package com.example.arab;

                 import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
            import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ImageView;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
                ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

                private int[] mImages = new int[] {R.drawable.alif,R.drawable.baa,R.drawable.taa,R.drawable.saa,R.drawable.gim,R.drawable.haa,
                                                    R.drawable.kha,R.drawable.dal,R.drawable.zal,R.drawable.raa,R.drawable.jaa,R.drawable.seen,
                                                    R.drawable.shin,R.drawable.soad,R.drawable.duad,R.drawable.tua,R.drawable.jua,R.drawable.aiin,
                                                    R.drawable.guain,R.drawable.faa,R.drawable.kaff,R.drawable.kuff,R.drawable.lum,R.drawable.mim,
                                                    R.drawable.nun,R.drawable.wow,R.drawable.haasmall,R.drawable.hamza,R.drawable.eaa};


                private int[] mAudio= new int[]{R.raw.alif,R.raw.baa,R.raw.taa,R.raw.saa,R.raw.gim,R.raw.haa,R.raw.kha,R.raw.dal,R.raw.zal,
                                                R.raw.raa,R.raw.jaa,R.raw.seen,R.raw.shin,R.raw.soad,R.raw.duad,R.raw.tua,R.raw.jua,R.raw.aiin,
                                                R.raw.guain,R.raw.faa,R.raw.kaff,R.raw.kuff,R.raw.lum,R.raw.mim,R.raw.nun,R.raw.wow,R.raw.haa_small,
                                                R.raw.hamza,R.raw.eaa};
                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                return mImages.length;
                  }
                @Override
                public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                   return view == ((ImageView) object);
                      }
                @Override
                public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                     Context context = MainActivity.this;
                   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
                   int padding =context.getResources().  
                           getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
                   imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
                   imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
                   imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
                   ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0); 


    //for Sound 
     if (mp != null) {
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.release();

                }

//the audio files are running here but not in sync with image
               mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,mAudio[position]);
                  mp.start();




    return imageView;
            }
                @Override
                public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                  ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
                }
            }
            }
```

here the int[] mAudio is the array where i saved all my audio files. now i want to play sound and change audio in accordance with the images in the int[] mImages array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

call your picture change function after completion of

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release(); //here you should call your picture changed function or event what ever you have for pictures}
```

using loop  u can change your audio accordance to your images.
for example if your image is changed obviously your index will also changed use the same index for your audio as well 
 like this

```
for (int i=0;i<mImages .length;i++)
mImages [i];
mp = MediaPlayer.create(FallAnimationActivity.this,
                        mAudio [i]);
                mp.start();
```

Comment: i have added the audio player and it plays audios but it is not synchronized with the pictures. what should i do...

Comment: call your picture change function after completion of mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
         public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
          mp.release();
here you should call your picture changed event